# Using subprocess.Popen messing Ubuntu terminal output

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

Using subprocess.Popen messing Ubuntu terminal output

```
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen("sudo ./agt_internal", shell=True, cwd="/home/boblittle/AGT/")
time.sleep(10)

for i in range(10):
    print('Good Morning America')
```

The terminal output is messed up. Any suggestions?
[image]

```
def start_agt_pmlog():
    command = 'sudo ./agt_internal -unilog=PM'
    args = shlex.split(command)
    print(f'Starts AGT PMLog')
    subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, cwd="/home/boblittle/AGT/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I chaged the code with a suggested solution by adding the function above. It didn't help.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen()` didn't do that, `agt_internal` did.

Comment: aperantly `agt_internal` it is modifying the terminal .... so maybe just open it in a new terminal, unfortunately that's sort of hard to do in a platform-independent way, you'd have to launch `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` or `xterm` based on what's available ... or contact whoever created that binary to fix his binary, in short, the carrige return character is not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a simple solution. Adding subprocess.run("reset", shell=True). It clears the terminal but it's good enough for me.

```
import subprocess
import time

subprocess.Popen("sudo ./agt_internal", shell=True, cwd="/home/boblittle/AGT/")
time.sleep(10)

subprocess.run("reset", shell=True)
for i in range(10):
    print('Good Morning America')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use shlex.split(), you have a missing double quote and also you should pass the stdout and stderr parameters to subprocess.Pope to avoid your terminal messing up.

```
import subprocess
import time
import shlex

command = "sudo ./agt_internal"
args = shlex.split(command)

subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, cwd="/home/boblittle/AGT/", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(10)

for i in range(10):
    print('Good Morning America')
```

Comment: Thank you. It didn't solve the problem. I updated my question.